# javascript placed inside an usercontrol loads but does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

inside a user control I have placed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert("foooo");

        };        
</script>
```

This javascript loads into the browser fine, but does not executes. What is the proper way to add javascript code to a user control in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: last line should be end with `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a close paren at the end of your function. It should be like this:

```
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with asp.net but the above is invalid JavaScript (no closing right parenthesis). Have you tried some very simple code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("foo");
</script>
```

Comment: once i closed the parenthesis, it worked. sorry for silly question. i should have cought that before posting.

Comment: It happens. Glad to hear you're in business.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have JQuery library referenced. Check it like with below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    if(JQuery == "undefined") { 

          alert("you didn't referenced the JQuery properly!")
    }

        $(function () {
            alert("foooo");

        });        
</script>
```